# Escribir en archivo no funciona

Tags: java, txt

Hola tengo este codigo y no funciona, cual podra ser el problema?

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            File f = new File("D:/archivo.txt");
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);          
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            
            bw.write("texto a escribir");
                          
        }catch(IOException e){
                    
        }
    }
}
```

Ese codigo deberia escribir "texto a escribir" en el archivo .txt que tengo en mi disco D.

Answer (score 0):

Es importante que cierres el flujo tanto de `BufferedWriter` y `FileWriter` al final de tu código.

```
bw.close();
fw.close();
```

Una vez realizado este paso, ya te mostrará el texto en tu archivo.

Ejemplo completo:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            File f = new File("D:/archivo.txt");
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);          
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        
            bw.write("texto a escribir");

            bw.close();
            fw.close();
                      
        }catch(IOException e){
                
        }
    }
}
```